# PyQT, error to load data from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, qpixmap

I am getting an error violation access when I try to set a pixmap from a numpy array.

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0ca00020
```

The utilization of a numpy array is a requirement.... Anyway i wouldn't give problems

This is the code, the error is in the setPixmap operation.

```
    from scipy import misc 
    numpy_image_uint8 = misc.imread('test.jpeg')
    #info_image=images[0]    
    #numpy_image_uint8=info_image.frames[0]
    numpy_image_uint32 = numpy_image_uint8.astype(np.uint32).copy()
    img = (255 << 24 | numpy_image_uint32[:,:,0] << 16 | numpy_image_uint32[:,:,1] << 8 | numpy_image_uint32[:,:,2]).flatten() # pack RGB values 
    imgQ = QImage(img,640,480,QImage.Format_RGB32)
    #imgQ = QImage(QtCore.QString('test.jpeg'))
    self.item.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(imgQ))
```

Furthermore, two interesting points:

- If i use a loaded `QImage` from a file, it works, like this:

  ```
  imgQ = QImage(QtCore.QString('test.jpeg'))
  ```
- If i save the `imgQ` variable, the saved image seems correct:

  ```
  imgQ = QImage(img,640,480,QImage.Format_RGB32)
  imgQ.save("test_image.bmp")
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `imgQ` shares memory with `img`, you need keep `img` alive.

try this:

```
self.img = img
imgQ = QImage(self.img,640,480,QImage.Format_RGB32)
```

Can you give more information that why you do this?

Comment: I am a newbie with pyqt (and Qt), I am trying to update a GraphicsView in a UI, and this is the source code which i could do work... I didn't know which it is necessary "keep alive" the variables.. Is it a issue related with python and the garbage collector?

Comment: Why you load the image into an array, and then convert it to QImage, but don't load the QImage directly from the file? When the garbage collector free the img array, it will release the data area, and QImage will have a wild pointer.

Comment: @carlos.baez If you look at the c++ documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html) you'll see that the buffer passed to the `QImage` constructor must remain valid throughout the life of the `QImage`. Since the QImage exists for as long as the `QPixmap` does, so must your buffer (`img`). Note that some Qt classes take ownership of items created (like adding a widget to a layout) so you don't need to hold onto references to prevent Python from garbage collecting them. But in this case Qt does not take ownership of the buffer so you have to keep it around yourself!

Comment: @HYRY, This code is a part of an application, i have another module which uses ctypes to load images from a webcam and i use numpy to convert the received data correctly. I agree, the code is confusing because i tried to simulate which i am receiving the image from the camera with numpy instead of loading the image directly...